# Displaying MYSQL data filtered for value of input field using PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I am new here, so any suggestion is welcome.

I have a situation where I am using a javascript filter function in order to select a value for an input field. On submit, a php script is run which filters based on the value of the input field in question. For some reason this is not working and as I am new I think its a common error. Clearly something small is wrong here and it is driving me mad. I wanted to improve this and get a best practice solution here.

Find below the code in question:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="searchContainer">
    <div id="productDiv">
        <form autocomplete="off" onsubmit="search(this.value)">
            <div class="autocomplete">  
                <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function search(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("products").value = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "filterMerchant.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

**PHP - (filterMerchant.php):**

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');

$q = intval($_GET['q']);

mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"theDB");
$search="SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE ref = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$search);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<a class=\"merchantOutput\">" . $row['merch'] . "</a>";
echo "<a class=\"priceOutput\"><strong>" . $row['cost'] . "</strong></a>";
echo "<img src=\"img.png\" style=\"height:42px;width:42px;\" 
onclick=\"showMerchant(this.value)\" value=\"TestProfile\" 
class=\"merchantLink\">";       
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: See the highliting. One `"` is not escaped.

Comment: "best practice" is dependable to overall project. if You app is small and it's easy manageable for now, so why You're searching for other practices? ok: use `slim framework` (https://www.slimframework.com/docs/) , use `eloquent orm` with it (https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/database-eloquent.html) , at frontend put jquery, angular or etc what You prefer. see, it's getting complicated for first time (:

Comment: @u_mulder might be being stupid here, but highlighting?

Comment: @NickSF The coloring in the code block.

Comment: That's why I try to avoid using the same kind of quotes inside the string as the string delimiters themselves. PHP and HTML both allow you to use either single or double quotes, so if you use double quotes in PHP, use single quotes in HTML, then you usually don't have to escape anything.

Comment: @NickSF better switch to `Laravel` and be happy, it has all best practices conventions out of box (:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EU7PRmCpx-0&list=PLillGF-RfqbYhQsN5WMXy6VsDMKGadrJ-

Comment: @Barmar I don't think this is a quote/syntax problem though, unless I've missed something because I've been staring at it too long?

Comment: @NickSF You edited the question to remove the syntax error.

Comment: "this is not working" is not a helpful problem description. What input are you giving, what result are you expecting, what are you getting instead?

Comment: Edited in line with previous comments. The input is any text in the input box per the HTML, the expected result would be the filter and display of the MySQL table as noted, but for some reason this filtering and disply is not happening? :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default form submission. You can do this by returning `false` from the `onsubmit` code.

```
<form autocomplete="off" onsubmit="search(this.value);return false">
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I'll have a check of this!

Comment: this does not actually solve anything? returning false simply avoids the submission of the form and running of the php filter script?

Comment: When you submit the form the JavaScript stops executing and you never see the result of the PHP script. The page is refreshed instead.

Comment: The Javascript is needed in order for the the PHP script (in this case filterMerchant.php) to execute per the above code? Or am I confused on that? I really want to solve this because it seems like an issues others could have

Comment: If you want to display the result of the search in the DIV without reloading the page, you need the JavaScript.

Comment: Is it still not working with this fix? Have you checked Developer Tools? Check for errors in the console, and use the Network tab to see what parameters you're sending and what response you're receiving.

Comment: Hmm, ok this is confusing. How would the JavaScript then be included without reloading the page?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The JavaScript is already in the HTML of the page, isn't it? And the whole point is that it uses AJAX to get the search results and display them in the DIV, instead of submitting the form normally.

Comment: Ok, maybe let me go back a bit. Currently what is happening and where I believe the above code is not working is that it is not recognizing the text in the input field (myInput). You're spot on with the above, but what I meant is that on submitting the form, nothing happens in terms of updating the div innerhtml (id=products) as shown in the javascript function above. All code is correctly included or referneced, its just a matter of the search input from "myInput" being recognised in the filter? Hope I'm making sense?

Comment: What's the value of the search field that you're sending? If it contains any special characters, you should use `encodeURIComponent(str)` when putting it in the URL. Does the query work if you execute it by hand?

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab? The browser has powerful debugging tools to help you follow what's happening.

Comment: input in the search field is just a normal string, sometimes including a space, no special characters (just a list of items). No errors in the browser inspector either. This is why I'm here (also thanks for your help and time. Thats what makes SO great :) )

Comment: What do you see in the response section of the Network tab of DevTools?

Comment: Do you mean  a comma-separated list? Is that an exact match for what's in the `ref` field of the table? `WHERE ref = '$q'` doesn't do list membership test, it just tests if the `ref` field is exactly the same as `$q`.

Comment: Add `echo $search;` to the PHP script, then try executing the query by hand.

Comment: There is an autocomplete function for the population of the input field which relies on an array of items (not relevant to the problem as this works perfectly). The array is an exact match for the items in the 'ref' column of the mySQL table (also works fine on testing it.

Comment: I haven't worked much with the response section of DevTools, but I see the source of the page I'm looking at ?

Comment: You shouldn't see the source of the original page, you should see the response from `filterMerchant.php`.